# How to update submodule ref?

Tags: git

I moved the source code of a submodule to GitHub by simply creating new repository and copying the sources (not by moving entire repository).

In the root repository I changed the submodule URL:

```
git submodule set-url lib/MyLib https://github.com/me/MyLib.git
```

but obviously submodule ref become wrong, and when I try

```
git submodule update
```

I get:

```
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref a02c00e0c81a170a133f57ed3e8477010cc2f461
fatal: Fetched in submodule path 'lib/MyLib', but it did not contain a02c00e0c81a170a133f57ed3e8477010cc2f461. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `git submodule update`, git tries to checkout the commit with the *a02c00e* hash in your submodule but is not able to find it. This most likely happens because this commit belongs to your former submodule repository. When you created your new Github repo and copied your source code, you created a new commit, with its own new hash.

What you could do is:

```
cd lib/MyLib # Go into submodule
git fetch
git checkout main # Checkout main branch from new repo (assuming main)
cd ../.. # Go back to root repo
git commit -am "Set submodule to existing commit" # Record submodule commit
```